# Piecewise transformation of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

I made up a problem yesterday and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Suppose $X$ is exponential with mean $1$, so that $F_{X}(x) = 1 - e^{-x}$, $x > 0$.

I am interested in finding $F_{Y}(y)$, where $$Y = \begin{cases}
X^2, & 0 < X \leq 2 \\
\sqrt{X}, & X > 2\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

I'm not sure if this is even a doable problem to start. Here's how I figure the problem. For a particular value $Y = y$, consider the following cases: $y \in (0, \sqrt{2})$, $y \in [\sqrt{2}, 4)$, $y \in [4, \infty)$.

In the first case, for $y \in (0, \sqrt{2})$:
$$\Pr\left(Y \leq y\right) = \Pr\left(Y \leq y \mid 0 < X \leq 2\right)\Pr\left(0 < X \leq 2\right)+\Pr\left(Y \leq y \mid X > 2 \right)\Pr\left(X > 2\right)\text{.}$$ 
How would I go about evaluating the conditional statements? I know for a fact that given $X > 2$, $\Pr\left(Y \leq y\right)$ should *probably* be $0$? But I have no idea how to justify this.

Comment: For $y\le\sqrt2$, simply use $(Y\le y)=(X\le\sqrt{y})$. Likewise for the two other intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, it is enough to compute $\mathbb{P}[Y\leq t]$ for any $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$. If $t\in(0,\sqrt{2})$,
$$\mathbb{P}[Y\leq t]=\mathbb{P}[0\leq X \leq \sqrt{t}] = \int_{0}^{\sqrt{t}}e^{-u}\,du = 1-e^{-\sqrt{t}}.\tag{1}$$
If $t\in(\sqrt{2},4)$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\mathbb{P}[Y\leq t]&=&\mathbb{P}[Y\leq \sqrt{2}]+\mathbb{P}[\sqrt{2}\leq Y\leq t]\\&=&1-e^{-\sqrt{2}}+\mathbb{P}[2^{1/4}\leq X\leq t^{1/2}]+\mathbb{P}[2\leq X\leq t^2]\\&=&1-e^{-\sqrt{2}}+e^{-2^{1/4}}-e^{-t^{1/2}}+e^{-2}-e^{-t^2}.\tag{2} \end{eqnarray*}$$
If $t>4$, 
$$ \mathbb{P}[Y\leq t]=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq 4]+\mathbb{P}[4\leq Y\leq t]=\mathbb{P}[Y\leq 4]+\mathbb{P}[16\leq X\leq t^2].\tag{3}$$